# Determine if page is the Posts Page

Tags: posts, pages

On the **Reading Settings** page you can set a "Front Page" and a "Posts Page". You can check whether the current page `is_front_page();`

Is there a similar function for the "Posts Page". I have noticed that `is_page();` does not work for this special page.

Thanks

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`is_home()` checks for the "Posts Page", despite the somewhat confusing function name.

Comment: thanks, i thought i checked them all, but i guess not...

Comment: What about `$wp_query->is_posts_page`?

Comment: @WestonRuter has the correct answer to the  question.

Answer (score 11):

Wordpress comes with 7 primary template page types, which can be determined on this way

```
if ( is_main_query() ) {
    // Error
    if ( is_404() ) {
        ;
    }
    // Front page
    if ( is_front_page() ) {
        ;
    }
    // Archive
    if ( is_archive() ) {
        ;
    }
    // Comments popup
    if ( is_comments_popup() ) {
        ;
    }
    // Search
    if ( is_search() ) {
        ;
    }
    // Singular
    if ( is_singular() ) {
        ;
    }
    // Home - the blog page
    if ( is_home() ) {
        ;
    }
}
```

is_home tells to you, that you have the blog page.

Answer (score 2):

"Posts page" is usually an archive of:

- posts of a category
- posts of a tag
- posts of a date ( year, month...)
- posts of main archive

Each one of these can be checked by a one of the many conditional tags like
`is_category()
is_tag()
is_date() 
is_archive()`
And so many more. To get a better understanding head over to the codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

Answer (score 2):

**First check the blogs related things like author, tag, post type**

```
function is_blog () {
        global  $post;
        $posttype = get_post_type($post );
        return ( ((is_archive()) || (is_author()) || (is_category()) || (is_home()) || (is_single()) || (is_tag())) && ( $posttype == 'post')  ) ? true : false ;
  }
```

Now check and return something which you want to have

```
function check_post_type(){
    $postType;
    if (is_blog())
      {
         $postType = 'I am post';
      } else
       {
          $postType = 'I am page';
       };
    return $postType;
  }
```

Use it like Boss
**`<?php echo check_post_type();?>`**

Thanks to [Wes Bos](https://gist.github.com/wesbos/1189639)

Comment: this one just helped me when customizing the post.php edit for pages only.

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

**Case A**. There is no need to determine it inside the main template file (index.php) because it is the default template for it<sup>[1]</sup>.

**Case B**. To determine it inside a page template (ex: page.php), simply check it like so:

```php
get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) == get_the_ID()
```

### Details

I literally went digging the source-code<sup>[2]</sup> of it just to be able to know how wordpress does the checking of the value. It turns out, it is using the statement `get_option( 'page_for_posts' )` to know the post ID of the selected value of the **Posts page**.

So yeah, for this purpose, there is no such official checker function that is similar to `is_front_page()`.

As long as you know the ID of the page that you've selected then you can use it for the checking process.

#### References

1. WordPress Codex, Theme Development, [codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/options-reading.php)
2. Source-code of **Settings** › **Reading Settings**, [github.com/WordPress/.../wp-admin/options-reading.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/options-reading.php)

Answer (score 1):

https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags in WordPress Codex sais that you can reference pages like so:

```
if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) {
  // Default homepage
} elseif ( is_front_page() ) {
  // static homepage
} elseif ( is_home() ) {
  // blog page
} else {
  //everything else
}
```